# How can I check if Play Slick filter has returned some rows or an empty result?

Tags: scala, slick, play-slick

I have the  below code which returns `Future[Option[Password]]`

```
db.run(passwords.filter {
      x => x.providerID === loginInfo.providerID && x.providerKey === loginInfo.providerKey
    }.result.headOption)
```

What I want to do is as in the below pseudo code:

```
if above query returns no results
  do nothing
else
  return new PasswordInfo(abovequeryresult.hasher, abovequeryresult.password, abovequeryresult.salt)
```

I am new to Scala and have no clue about this. Tried to use `flatMap` like in below example, but the `flatMap` signature for the above `db.run()` is different.

```
find(loginInfo).flatMap {
      case Some(_) => update(loginInfo, authInfo)
      case None => add(loginInfo, authInfo)
    }
```

I am using Play Slick version 1.1.1

Comment: What does `update/add` return?  `flatMap` expects an `Option[T]` in its body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is more related to how manipulate [Futures](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) in Scala. If your `db.run` code runs in an action of a Play Controller, the best option is to declare the actions as `async` and map the result of query to an `play.api.mvc.Result`. Something like this:

```
def someAction = Action.async {
  find(loginInfo).map {
    case Some(authInfo) => 
      update(loginInfo, authInfo)
      Ok("Updated AuthInfo")               //Return a play.api.mvc.Resul 
    case None => 
      add(loginInfo, authInfo)
      Created("CreatedAuthInfo")           //Return another play.api.mvc.Resul
  }
}
```

Or if you only want the result

```
val future = find(loginInfo)
future.onSuccess {
  case Some(authInfo) => update(loginInfo, authInfo)
  case None => add(loginInfo, authInfo)
}
Await.ready(future, Duration.Inf)
```